# Is there a way to get function parameter names, including bound-methods excluding `self`?

Tags: python, function, methods, reflection

I can use `inspect.getargspec` to get the parameter names of any function, including bound methods:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class C(object):
...     def f(self, a, b):
...             pass
...
>>> c = C()
>>> inspect.getargspec(c.f)
ArgSpec(args=['self', 'a', 'b'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
>>>
```

However, `getargspec` includes `self` in the argument list.

Is there a universal way to get the parameter list of any function (and preferably, any callable at all), excluding `self` if it's a method?

EDIT: Please note, I would like a solution which would on both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @Flippy Nope :) These answers don't talk about methods.

Comment: Why must it be excluded? `self` _is_ a parameter of those methods. Why should that be treated specially?

Comment: @JeffMercado Because I'm going to be invoking that function by itself, and `self` will already be passed into it implicitly anyway, being a bound method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature) excludes the first argument of methods:

```
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> list(signature(c.f).parameters)
['a', 'b']
```

You could also delete the first element of `args` manually:

```
from inspect import ismethod, getargspec

def exclude_self(func):
    args = getargspec(func)
    if ismethod(func):
        args[0].pop(0)
    return args

exclude_self(c.f) # ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b'], ...)
```

Comment: Is there a solution which works both on Python 2 and 3?

Comment: @AvivCohn: I just posted it. Note that `getargspec` is gone in Python 3.6.

Comment: To support both Python 2 and 3, I think I'll combine both yours and @Flippy's suggestions: get the arguments using `f.func_code.co_varnames[:f.func_code.co_argcount]` if it's a function or `f.func_code.co_varnames[1:f.func_code.co_argcount]` if it's a method. Thanks

Comment: @AvivCohn: what's stopping you from using the second solution from my answer?